# ModelMapper is taking toString method to convert property?

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper to map Entities to DTO's in my spring boot application.

Now I have something strange I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MileStoneEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectEntity_id")
    private ProjectEntity project;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = CompanyUserEntity.class)
    private Set<CompanyUserEntity> projectManagers;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = TaskEntity.class, mappedBy = "mileStone")
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasks;
    private boolean archived;

        public List<Long> projectManagersIds() {
        return projectManagers.stream().map(CompanyUserEntity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Long> taskIds() {
        return tasks.stream().map(TaskEntity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectEntity_id")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CompanyUserEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CompanyUserEntity executor;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = MileStoneEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mileStoneEntity_id")
    private MileStoneEntity mileStone;
    private boolean archived;
    private boolean replaceStartAndEndDateWithMileStone;
}

public static PropertyMap<MileStoneEntity, MileStoneDto> mileStoneEntityToMap = new PropertyMap<MileStoneEntity, MileStoneDto>() {
    protected void configure() {
        map().setProjectId(source.getProject().getId());
        map().setProjectManagers(source.projectManagersIds());
        map().setTasks(source.taskIds());
    }
};
```

DTO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MileStoneDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long projectId;
    private List<Long> projectManagers;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private String description;
    private List<Long> tasks;
    private boolean archived;
}
```

Now this doesn't work I get this error:

> "ModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Converter
>   org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter@ad01ae2 failed to
>   convert entity.TaskEntity to java.lang.Long

But when I then add a toString method like this in the TaskEntity:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ""+id+"";
}
```

then everything works. So why is ModelMapper taking the toString to convert the id to a Long?

EDIT

```
@Bean
ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    modelMapper.addMappings(ProjectMappings.mileStoneEntityToMap);


    return modelMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the same types in your entity and your dto:

**Entity**

```
private Set<TaskEntity> tasks;
```

**DTO**

```
private List<Long> tasks;
```

ModelMapper does not know how to convert the TaskEntity to a Long.

You have to write a converter for this purpose:

http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/

Comment: But I defined a propertyMap and I did it for a lot of other entities and it works. You see I call a method to get the longs?

Comment: This seems not to be called. Where do you configure this?

Comment: Where I create the new ModelMapper() I put that propertyMap on it.

Comment: I created a converter and now it works. Weird that it works on all other entities except this one. Thanks for your help!